# C++ How to read from a file to do a count controlled loop?

Tags: c++, loops

I'm currently working on a homework assignment where we have to read from a text file which houses an ID number, and that ID's blood pressure. With that, part of the assignment asks us to create a count controlled loop to read the blood pressures listed and sum them up. This is what I've come up with so far.

text file:

```
1234   4   100 101 102 103
3625   6   105 120 154 132 188 153
```

part of the code pertaining to these items:

```
while (count > 0)
{
    inData >> BP;
    total = total + BP;
    count--;
    cout << total << endl;
}
```

and what this comes up for me is it just adds up the last blood pressure (BP) together 6 times. Any help is appreciated as I just started c++ this semester I am fairly nooby with it. Thank you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code (well, I could nitpick on a few irrelevant details, but there are no logical problems here). Please edit your question, and include a [mcve].

Comment: This code _fragment_ looks fine, if not necessarily idiomatic. What is your problem?

Comment: I've figured out my problem now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to calculate a sum you need to place the output of the `total` outside the loop

```
while (count > 0)
{
    inData >> BP;
    total = total + BP;
    count--;
}
cout << total << endl;
```

Then you will output the result only once.

Comment: @JustinFarr If the answer was helpful and it solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.